# How to align bootstrap icon with text in button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to align bootstrap icon and image to bottom? ( I am using font-awsome for icons ).

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/uwupuz/2/edit

[image]

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
    <a class="btn" href="#">
      <i class="icon-plus"></i>
      <span>Add</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        <span>Remove</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">
      <i class="icon-edit"></i>
      <span>Edit</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/CBss2/1/  this is what it looks like after applying `line-height: 1;`

[image: button screen cap]

I wouldn't mess with the `position` property as suggested by @hajpoj, there are cleaner ways to fix the problem that won't have cascading effects later.  The other problem with using `position: relative` is that each icon is actually a little bit different in size. You want to try to keep maintenance down by accounting for that. It's best to make it *appear* as if it's bottom-aligned for most normal sized icons, and when a larger-than-average icon is used it is centered properly with the text. Using `position: relative` a larger icon will push above the others and look off-center.

Comment: good points, I wouldn't apply position relative to all icons, just ones you wanted to fine tune.  btw in your jsfiddle your line-height is getting over ridden by more specific css.

Comment: yes, true - thanks for reminding me to mention that part @hajpoj. the universal selectors applied to icons in bootstrap will always override unless you increase specificity or use !important (I wouldn't recommend doing either), so the line-height needs to be adjusted at the source. Line height is most effective because it will adjust with the text around it. However, I'm not above using hajpoj's solution when all else fails - so that can come in handy too

Answer (score 0):

You can use position relative.

```
i {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px; // or however much you want to offset it by
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/ZdPGe/